# Spark + Druid Tranquility - library version conflict

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, druid

I get following error when I run a spark job with Druid Tranquility.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS
```

Druid Tranquility uses higher version of jackson-databind (2.6.1) than what is bundled in spark. 
I'm using latest stable versions of Druid Tranquility(0.6.4) and Spark(1.5.2).

How to resolve this?

1. Force spark to use the classes supplied with the job and not the classes bundled in spark. How?
2. Compile spark with the new version of jackson-databind
3. Force Tranquility to use old version.  (Doesn't seem to work, tried to exclude in sbt)
4. Any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gian has given a pull request https://github.com/druid-io/tranquility/pull/81 with downgrade Jackson to match the version in Druid.
And announced that next version of tranquility will have it.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can force Spark to use classes supplied with the job using `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` configuration options, which will prepend anything you specify there to the classpath of Spark driver or Spark executor respectively.
2. You can try to compile Spark against newer version of `jackson-databind`. To do that, update `fasterxml.jackson.version` configuration parameter in Spark's pom.xml file, then follow the Spark [build instructions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-a-runnable-distribution). It's not guaranteed that it will compile successfully though.
3. Excluding jackson from your Tranquility application might work too, just make sure to exclude the following artifacts:

   com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core
   com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations
   com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile
   com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda
   com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind

You can verify that these artifacts are excluded by running `sbt dependency-tree` (using [this](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plug-in).

I'd first try (3) then (2) and (1).

Comment: I had a similar issue and setting spark.driver.extraClassPath with --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/<path_to_jar>" fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add --jars hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar in the spark-submit, this may help